# Regular expression search for *Stream #0:0(und): Video:* or *Stream #0:0: Audio* in output python3.5

Tags: regex, python-3.5

I am trying to parse an **output** which looks like this:

```
b"Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '../abc/def/vid.mp4':\n  Metadata:\n    major_brand     : isom\n    minor_version   : 512\n    compat
ible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41\n    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101\n  Duration: 00:03:40.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 445 kb/s\n    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 /
 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 311 kb/s, 29.92 fps, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.83 tbc (default)\n    Metadata:\n      handler_name    : VideoHandler\n    Stream #
0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)\n    Metadata:\n      handler_name    : SoundHandler\nOutput #0, null, to 'pipe:':\n  M
etadata:\n    major_brand     : isom\n    minor_version   : 512\n    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41\n    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101\n    Stream #0:0(und): Video: rawvi
deo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.92 fps, 29.92 tbn, 29.92 tbc (default)\n    Metadata:\n      handler_name    : VideoHandler\n
    encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 rawvideo\n    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s (default)\n    Metadata:\n      handler_name    : SoundHan
dler\n      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s16le\nStream mapping:\n  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))\n  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> pcm_s1
6le (native))\nPress [q] to stop, [?] for help\n[null @ 0x7af4c0] Encoder did not produce proper pts, making some up.\nframe= 1434 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:48.06 bitra
te=N/A    \rframe= 2718 fps=2715 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:30.97 bitrate=N/A    \rframe= 4183 fps=2785 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:19.94 bitrate=N/A    \rframe= 5494 fps=2743 q=
-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:03.78 bitrate=N/A    \rframe= 6590 fps=2765 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:03:40.35 bitrate=N/A    \nvideo:618kB audio:37960kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB
global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown\n"
```

I want to find a **pattern** in this whose starting looks like this:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video:
```

Or a **pattern** that looks like this:

```
Stream #0:0: Audio:
```

So, I tried this regular expression for it in python3.5:

```
re.search("^\s*Stream[\s.]*:\s(Video|Audio)[\s.]*", data)
```

since the output(which needs parsing) is byte string, I have converted that using `output.decode("utf-8")`.
But, it the output of `re.search(...)` is None, **so isn't this the right regular expression to find the *pattern* in *output*** ?

Comment: Maybe something like [`re.search(r"(?ms)^\s*Stream\s*#[\d:]+\([^()]*\):\s*Video:\s(.*?)(?=^\s*Metadata:|\Z)", data)`](https://regex101.com/r/uaHRwa/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, that certainly helped, but it needs some tweaks, see my updated question

Comment: What are the expected matches? Please update the question. Also, see https://regex101.com/r/uaHRwa/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[\s.]*` matches 0 or more chars that are `.` (dots) or whitespaces (`\s`).

Besides, you need to actually get the text after them, so you need a dot matching pattern that can match across lines up to the next "keyword" or end of string.

So, I suggest

```
(?m)^\s*Stream.*?(?:Audio|Video):\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=^\s*Metadata:|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uaHRwa/4)

**Details**:

- `(?m)` - a `re.M` inline modifier
- `^` - start of a *line*
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `Stream` - a literal string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible,
  up to the first...
- `(?:Audio|Video):` - either `Audio:` or `Video:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([\s\S]*?)` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first...
- `(?=^\s*Metadata:|\Z)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `^\s*Metadata:` - start of a line, whitespaces, and `Metadata:` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `\Z` - the very end of string.

USAGE NOTE: You can get just the text matched with `([\s\S]*?)` if you run it with `re.findall`.

Comment: thanks, this worked, although I tried only this portion of `(?m)^\s*Stream.*?(?:Audio|Video):\s*` of your answer, and that too worked for me. Accepting this as answer.

Comment: Ok, glad I could help you figure out what you need. Next time please consider adding at least 1 example of the expected result.